# MVC2 Slash char in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url, maproute

I want to use encrypted strings in MVC2 urls.  A typical url in my app looks like this:

```
http://localhost:29558/Account/PasswordReset/ZKGeDMZikfIsnO8/MEs7SCBlI+MZo1Je8LM5dTEeCt3u91ARPUcavT5UXfVVRfyE
```

Note that everything after PasswordReset/ is the encrypted string.  In the example the encrypted string contains a slash, and this is causing MVC to crash.

I've tried adding a MapRoute in Global.asax.cs as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "PasswordResetSpecialCase", // Route name
                "Account/PasswordReset/*", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Account", action = "PasswordReset" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

but MVC2 is still falling over because the encrypted string contains a slash char.  If I remove the slash then it works, but obviously that's no good.
How do I get MVC2 to regard everything after the PasswordReset as pure data?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maproute contains an error. Replace the `*` with `{*nameOfParameter}`